# Performance vs clean code?

Tags: c#, performance

MSDN's performance tuning recommendations say this:

> Make Chunky Calls
>   A chunky call is a function call that performs several tasks, such as a method that initializes several fields of an object. This is to be viewed against chatty calls, that do very simple tasks and require multiple calls to get things done (such as setting every field of an object with a different call). It's important to make chunky, rather than chatty calls across methods where the overhead is higher than for simple, intra-AppDomain method calls. P/Invoke, interop and remoting calls all carry overhead, and you want to use them sparingly. In each of these cases, you should try to design your application so that it doesn't rely on small, frequent calls that carry so much overhead.

But how does that comply with the SOLID design principles? I am trying to tune performance on a brownfield Windows forms application, and I have been refactoring it to be more SOLID. Am I actually degrading performance to do this?

Comment: I'd say this is somewhat open to opinion. Could you provide a link where you referenced this from? How old is this reference?

Comment: How bad is [performance](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?  Did you profile it? Are you sure what chunky/chatty matter? Anyway it's too broad without concrete example of the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Sinatr. Can you provide an example?

Comment: It is very plain advice, in some cases the cost of a method call can become substantial.  When that happens, "clean" becomes the antipode of "fast".  It does not happen very often and you always know when you have a case like this.  And if you don't then a profiler will point the finger.

Comment: @user1666620 this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Too bad this question is on hold...  It is one of the most important and most interesting issues in client/server software design

Answer (score 3):

I think the important part is:

> where the overhead is higher than for simple, intra-AppDomain method
>   calls

So if you're calling a web service, make one call that returns all the data in one go rather than making multiple calls.  If you're calling a database, maybe get the Stored Procedure to return multiple recordsets rather than making lots of calls.  The code inside the web service or SP can then be SOLID, etc.